# Go struct type on an already typed struct

Tags: struct, go

I have a struct called `Service` in `package xyz` which multiple api wrappers (`Api1`, `Api2`) will use as a base. I want someone who is using the package to call the methods for each API like: `xyz.Api1.MethodA(..)` and `xyz.Api2.MethodB(..)`

Right now I'm doing something like this

```
type struct api1 {
    *Service
}

var Api1 *api1

func init() {
    Api1 = &api1{
        &Service{
            ...
        }
    }
}

func (a *api1) MethodA {
    ...
}
```

I'm not a fan of this because it seems like a lot of boilerplate. I would rather have Api1 be a Service struct but each service will have different methods so I don't think that's possible unless I could do `type Service api1 {...}`?

Is there another way to get the desired call by a user to be something like `xyz.Api1.MethodA(..)` without having to create a new struct type for each api and without having so much boilerplate?

Comment: Why not just make `api1` and `api2` separate packages? Also, do methods on APIs use the `Service` in any way?

Comment: Yes some methods would call a method on `Service`. If I was to separate `api1` and `api2` into their own packages could I refer to `Service` which would be in the parent package? Or I guess the question is can imports use relative path e.g. `import "../xyz"`?

Comment: It's recommended to never use relative paths for various reasons, but yeah, you can use it. Another possibility is to create two new exported types, `API1Service` and `API2Service`, define methods on them, and let users instantiate those and use however they want.

Comment: ahh I kind of like that. `Service` shouldn't even be public, expose functions that create whichever api and then have users instantiate it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using global variables you can just create two new types and let users decide how to use them:

```
type API1Service struct {
    *Service
    api1Param1 int
    // etc.
}

func NewAPI1Service(api1Param1 int) *API1Service { /* ... */ }

// methods on API1Service

type API2Service struct {
    *Service
    api2Param1 int
    // etc.
}

func NewAPI2Service(api2Param1 int) *API2Service { /* ... */ }

// methods on API2Service
```

Then, your users can do

```
api := xyz.NewAPI1Service(42)
api.MethodA()
// etc.
```